# Google play store wallet

Tags: google-play-store, google

It charged me a amount of 50 does it take a single time or for every purchase and y is this money taken and will I get the amount back and if there any one with the return of the money

Answer (score 0):

When you charge your wallet with a fixed amount, you are charged once, then all the future purchases are paid with the credit that you already have.

If you have an issue with an app and ask for a refund, then the money goes back to your available credit.